# $P(\limsup_nX_n\geq x)\geq\limsup_nP(X_n>x)?$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables. Does it hold that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ $$P(\limsup_nX_n\geq x)\geq\limsup_nP(X_n>x)?$$ If yes, what can be used to prove this?

Comment: Hello @user394691, welcome to MSE. Can you please add your attempts in the question and tell us where exactly you got stuck? This will make it easier for others to give an adequate answer for your question. Also, note that questions that show no attempts or that seem like "this is my question, solve it for me" are something not well received on this forum and might attract downvotes.

Comment: It seems like this should follow from Fatou's lemma but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

As @Math1000 pointed out, this comes from the [reverse Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

$$\limsup_nP(X_n\geq x) = \limsup_n\int 1_{(X_n \geq x)}dP \\
\leq \int \limsup_n 1_{(X_n\geq x)}dP = P(\limsup_n {(X_n\geq x)}).$$

To verify the conditions of the theorem are satisfied, one can simply use $g \equiv 1(\omega)$ as the non-negative integrable function.